# Facebook Canvas Iframe App Extended Permissions failing

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am attempting to create a Facebook IFrame Application using the Facebook Developer's Toolkit (language I'm using is VB). No matter what I do, I cannot get past this error message from Facebook.

> App may not request permissions that
>   do not apply to all profiles in the
>   selector

I have tried dropping a `CanvasIFrameLoginControl` with `requirelogin=true`

i have also tried inheriting `Facebook.Web.CanvasIFrameMasterPage` then adding `Me.RequireLogin = True` to the `Page_Init` event. Both of these do require login. As soon as I add Required permissions, however, I get the API Error Code 100 - an app may not request permissions that do not apply to all profiles in the selector error from facebook. Does anyone have any idea how I can get past this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get extended permission to access the user's information like email,birthday etc..

[Check This](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)